# PHP strip tags are not working

Tags: php, mysql, html, tags, xss

Im trying to remove xss scripting from my php forum i made. To do so i tried the strip_tags funciton. However when i tried it out. The tags still got posted and the xss scripting is not fixed . This is the code i tried . Whats wrong with it?

```
    // get data that sent from form 
$topic=$_POST['topic'];
$detail=$_POST['detail'];
$name=$_POST['name'];
$email=$_POST['email'];

$topic = strip_tags($topic);
$detail = strip_tags($detail);
$name = strip_tags($name);
$email = strip_tags($email);

$datetime=date("d/m/y h:i:s"); //create date time

$sql="INSERT INTO $tbl_name(topic, detail, name, email, datetime)VALUES('$topic', '$detail', '$name', '$email', '$datetime')";

$stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: xss ? More like sql injection.

Comment: No its xss. i inputed <script>alert(5);</script> and the paged did the alert

Comment: Is the content being outputted in script tags? Also @frz3993 is pointing out you are open to SQL injections with this code. Don't pass user input directly to your queries. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1 With strip_tags your content would be `alert(5);`.

Comment: @chris85 no, i did the tags in the detail input. After the alert shows up, detail is not showing anything .

Comment: You'll need to provide a reproducible example of this. http://3v4l.org/UDdqo Function works as expected, or provide the code where you are outputting this content.

Comment: Using the variables directly inside the query like that defeats the purpose of prepared statement. My suggestion, use prepared statement and bind the parameters when inserting to mysql and to display html use something like `htmlspecialchars($string, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");`.

Comment: @chris85 yeah , that’s the output i should get, but however, it doesn’t

Comment: echo `$sql` here what do you get?

Comment: @frz3993 yeah i was going to do that after i fixed the cross site scripting problem/.

Comment: @chris85 outputs blank string

Comment: there are a few issues with your code, and I've outlined them in my answer below, in case you haven't seen that yet. Commenting back and forth here for me, would have taken too much space.

Comment: You echoed after `$sql="INSERT INTO $tbl_name(topic, detail, name, email, datetime)VALUES('$topic', '$detail', '$name', '$email', '$datetime')";`? If you did than there is something wrong with your PHP. If not than move the echo after the value is set.

Comment: You're commenting under the 2nd answer and not doing anything with the one I posted first. I'm obviously going unheard and blowing bubbles here. I'm outta here.

Comment: @Fred-ii- you posted my issues not really a solution to fixing the removing tags. No offence  .

Comment: Seems like we are at a stand still here, good luck.

Comment: @chris85 yeah thanks chris, i appreciate the help, php drives me crazy.

Comment: @AndrewKralovec Sorry, I didn't properly grasp the question, my mistake. I have made an edit to my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit:** It seems I did not grasp the question, my mistake.

Use [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) for the inputs in your HTML form, rather than `strip_tags()` during/before the query and prepared statements; see my original answer for related links near the bottom.

Sidenote: Doing `$stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);` with the word "prepare", doesn't qualify as a prepared statement. You need to use the full and proper syntax.

I.e.:

```
<input name="var" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($var)?>">
```

There are also a few articles you can read on the subject:

- [XSS Cross Site Scripting Prevention Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_%28Cross_Site_Scripting%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet)
- https://www.owasp.org/index.php/PHP_Security_Cheat_Sheet

---

Original answer:

There are a few issues happening here.

Firstly, `datetime` and `name` are MySQL reserved words and you're not giving them special treatment.

wrap those column names in ticks

```
(topic, detail, `name`, email, `datetime`)
```

checking for errors would have signaled the syntax error(s).

- MySQLi error checking: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php
- PDO error checking: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php

It's unclear as to which MySQL API you're using to connect with, so use the appropriate error connection method.

What's also unclear is what `$tbl_name` is defined as.

If that table name contains spaces, or hyphens, or anything that MySQL will complain about, then wrap that variable in ticks also.

I.e.:

```
INSERT INTO `$tbl_name` (topic, detail, `name`, email, `datetime`)
```

If your date column is `DATETIME`, then MySQL stores those as YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS so `date("d/m/y h:i:s")` will fail.

Ref: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/datetime.html

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Displaying errors should only be done in staging, and never production.

---

**Using prepared statements**

Help prevent injection by consulting:

- [**How can I prevent SQL-injection in PHP?**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/) on Stack.
- Use [**prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO with prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements), *they're much safer*.

Sidenote: [`strip_tags()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) doesn't do anything to help prevent SQL injection.

Also make sure that your form does use a POST method and that your inputs bear the name attributes for them and not typos.

Comment: Ok, ill look more into it. Thanks for all the info

Comment: nice answer as always sir

Answer (score 0):

you should prevent sql-injection in this way:

replace

```
        $topic = strip_tags($topic);
        $detail = strip_tags($detail);
        $name = strip_tags($name);
        $email = strip_tags($email);

        $datetime=date("d/m/y h:i:s"); //create date time

        $sql="INSERT INTO $tbl_name(topic, detail, name, email, datetime)VALUES('$topic', '$detail', '$name', '$email', '$datetime')";
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
```

with

```
        $datetime=date("d/m/y h:i:s"); //create date time

        $sql="INSERT INTO $tbl_name(`topic`, `detail`, `name`, `email`, `datetime`)VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute([$topic, $detail, $name, $email, $datetime]);
```

and about xss-prevention you shoud use htmlspecialchars when OUTPUT text-fields TO BROWSER, somthing like:

NOT `echo $topic;` BUT `echo htmlspecialchars($topic);`

Comment: so you added the ticks I see, after ;-)

Comment: $topic = htmlspecialchars($topic);
$detail = htmlspecialchars($detail);
$name = htmlspecialchars($name);
$email = htmlspecialchars($email);                                                                         Didnt work

Comment: you can do it like this. yes. but i not recommend you. its better to store in database "clear input from user"